# Cannot download image using URLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, swift3, xcode8

I'm stuck on how to correctly use a `URLSession` task to download a J.S.Bach image into a `UIImage`.
This is the code inside `viewDidLoad`. No crashes occur. The program never reaches the innermost if statement, and `UIImageView` remains blank.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg")
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("some error!")
    } else {
        if let bach = UIImage(data: data!) {
            self.image.image = bach
        }
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: Check the response as well.

Comment: Try this url instead, as the one you're using returns a web page.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to load a web page into a `UIImage` instance. I suspect your `URLRequest` is working fine, but the line `if let bach` chokes because you're trying to create a `UIImage` out of some HTML. I realize the Wikipedia URL has ".jpg" in its path extension, but it still points to a HTML page.

To fix your problem, try changing the URL to be `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg` – that's the actual JPEG file you're looking for.

Comment: Fantastic! Your suggestions works. With the bad url the server response reported "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8"; instead with the good url the response reports "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg". Thanks!